# how to edit the JS date and time to update atuomatically?

Tags: javascript

I have got a very simple JS code the prints out Date and time / I'm good the the date part, 
the CLOCK thou doesn't update minutes automatically, how can I have it update minutes with out refreshing the page, NO NEED TO SHOW SECONDS / I just want to see minutes update automatically,

how can I alter this code to do that plz (I'm a beginner / please give me details)

```
    <script>
        var dt = new Date();
        document.getElementById("datendtime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleString([], {
            weekday: 'long',
            month: '2-digit',
            day: '2-digit',
            year: '2-digit',
            hour: '2-digit',
            minute: '2-digit'
        });
    </script>
```

HTML to print it:

```
<span id="datendtime"></span>
```

Comment: Looks to me like you'll need something like setTimeout (or setInterval) to execute the script again and again at regular intervals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Yishmeray said in the comments, you'll need to use something like `setInterval` which executes code at a set (although imprecise) interval.

Note that `setInterval` is not guaranteed to run at the exact interval you specify.

```js
setInterval(() => {
 document.getElementById("datendtime").innerHTML = refreshDate(new Date())
}, 1000)


  function refreshDate(date) {
    return date.toLocaleString([], {
      weekday: 'long',
      month: '2-digit',
      day: '2-digit',
      year: '2-digit',
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit'
    });
  }
```

```html
<div id="datendtime"></div>
```

Comment: sorry / got a quick question / wat was the 1000 for in setInterval ?

Comment: @user10366078 it's the time in milliseconds. [MDN is your friend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var screen = document.querySelector("p");

setInterval(function() {
  screen.innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleString([], {
    weekday: 'long',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
    year: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit'
  });
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: sorry / got a quick question / wat was the 1000 for in setInterval ?

Comment: it was how much milliseconds, so 1 second equals 1000 milliseconds

Comment: got you // thanx a lot